# Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010

I need help.

How do I programatically create a list of external links where you can choose if you want to open the link in a new window or not?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood what you are asking then I did something similar for SP2003:

1. Add a column to the Link list called 'New Window' of type 'Yes/No'
2. Using FrontPage (it was a while ago) I modifed the XSLT for the view (it was the only view and accessed via a listview webpart on the homepage): `if New Window = Yes then render the link with target="_blank"`

I think the theory for SP2010 should be the same.

Or you could just let the users decide.